# Assigning list of labels to radiobuttons using wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython

I have an array of file names which gets updated each time when the user opens a new file. I want the radio buttons with these file names as labels. Is there any function in wxpython like wxcheckboxlistbox which takes the array as input for radio buttons?
I started working with wxpython recently. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - it is called `wx.RadioBox`:

From the demo:

```
import  wx

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

class TestRadioBox(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, log):
        self.log = log
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, -1)
        #self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.BLUE)
    sampleList = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five',
                  'six', 'seven', 'eight']

    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

    rb = wx.RadioBox(
            self, -1, "wx.RadioBox", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize,
            sampleList, 2, wx.RA_SPECIFY_COLS
            )

    self.Bind(wx.EVT_RADIOBOX, self.EvtRadioBox, rb)
    #rb.SetBackgroundColour(wx.BLUE)
    rb.SetToolTip(wx.ToolTip("This is a ToolTip!"))
    #rb.SetLabel("wx.RadioBox")

    sizer.Add(rb, 0, wx.ALL, 20)

    rb = wx.RadioBox(
            self, -1, "", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize,
            sampleList, 3, wx.RA_SPECIFY_COLS | wx.NO_BORDER
            )

    self.Bind(wx.EVT_RADIOBOX, self.EvtRadioBox, rb)
    rb.SetToolTip(wx.ToolTip("This box has no label"))

    sizer.Add(rb, 0, wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.BOTTOM, 20)

    self.SetSizer(sizer)


def EvtRadioBox(self, event):
    self.log.WriteText('EvtRadioBox: %d\n' % event.GetInt())

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

def runTest(frame, nb, log):
    win = TestRadioBox(nb, log)
    return win



overview = """\
A RadioBox is used to select one of a number of mutually exclusive
choices.  It is displayed as a vertical column or horizontal row of
labelled buttons, surrounded by a box that can optionally have a 
label.

"""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys,os
    import run
    run.main(['', os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])] + sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, I want similar function for radiobuttons not for check boxes.

Comment: This is close to what I needed. Is it possible to have the list to be displayed vertically not horizontally?

Comment: Just change the number of cols 2/3 in the examples above to 1.

Comment: One more doubt, once my list is updated the radio box is getting overwritten and I doubt the previous box which was present on the panel is not being cleared(Multiple options are being selected). How can I clear it before updating on my panel?

Comment: If you are creating a new box you will need to delete the old one with Destroy.